# Calculate lateral drift when driving straight with 2D GPS data

Tags: matlab, gps

I have a set of GPS data in 2D. I want to calculate a 2D vector or function going straight through this set of data. When this vector/line is obtained I want to calculate the distances from the vector/line to each GPS data sample (90 degrees from the line) in order to determine how accurate the object with GPS have been moving straight.

I assume that the GPS measures without noise. The idea is illustrated in figure.

If anything is unclear about the question, please tell me!

Black: GPS data. Red: The most straight line through GPS data. Green distance from most straight line to GPS data sample.

[image: GPS DATA]

Comment: I see already that the figure was not added... I will try to add it

Comment: okay, the image is added you just have to click on the link: "Black: GPS data..."

Answer (score 0):

You can try [the formula about distance from point to a line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line)

if your red line has equation ac + by + c = 0 (you can surely retrieve it by interpolation) and your "external point" has coordinates x0,y0.